# How do I properly display user-generated images using django?

Tags: python, django, settings, models, imagefield

I am trying to upload a user-generated image and then display in on my django web app.  The image is getting uploaded to the server but I am having trouble displaying it.

## models.py

```
image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255, upload_to="images/")
```

## settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/webapps/static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://user.webfactional.com/static/'
```

As an example, say I upload I file named Finland.gif.  I can see the file uploaded.  However when I look at the source, I see the source of the image as "www.foo.com/accounts/profile/images/Finland.gif" and not the static image url which should be "http://user.webfactional.com/static/images/Finland.gif".  Any advice on how I should fix this?

Comment: Can u show the code used to display the image?

Comment: @Rakesh <img src = "{{userprofile.image}}">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userprofile.image.url` gives you the full url to the image

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it... I need to include:

```
http://user.webfactional.com/static/{{userprofile.image}}
```